# Can't connect CloudKit Data to Widgets

Tags: swift, swiftui, cloudkit, widgetkit

I'm trying to show data stored in a database through CloudKit in my Widgets. There's very little information on how to do this online, and I've tried everything I could. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
import ...

public class DataController : ObservableObject {
        
    static let shared = DataController()
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Stash")
    
    
    init(){
        
        guard let description = container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first else {fatalError("No Descriptions Found")}
        description.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentStoreRemoteChangeNotificationPostOptionKey)
        
        let url = URL.storeURL(for: "group.com.name.app", database: "Stash")
        let storeDescription = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: url)
        container.persistentStoreDescriptions.append(storeDescription)
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
                
        container.loadPersistentStores { description, error in
            if let error = error {
                fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.processUpdate), name: .NSPersistentStoreRemoteChange, object: nil)
    }
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
    func storeCurrentTime() {
        let currentTime = Date.now
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm d MMMM"
        
        let currentTimeString = formatter.string(from: currentTime)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(currentTimeString, forKey: "loa")
    }
    
    @objc
    func processUpdate(notification : NSNotification) {
        operationQueue.addOperation{
            
            let context = self.container.newBackgroundContext()
            context.performAndWait {
                let subjects : [Subject]
                do {
                    try subjects = context.fetch(Subject.getSubjectFetchRequest())
                    WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()
                } catch {
                    fatalError("Error in operation queue")
                }
                
                if context.hasChanges {
                    do {
                        try context.save()
                    } catch {
                        fatalError("Error saving to cloud")
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    lazy var operationQueue: OperationQueue = {
       var queue = OperationQueue()
        queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
        return queue
    }()
}

public extension URL {
    static func storeURL(for appGroup : String, database : String) -> URL {
        guard let fileContainer = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: appGroup) else {
            fatalError("Unable to create")
        }
        return fileContainer.appendingPathComponent("\(database).sqlite")
    }
}
```

This is the code in the data controller. The widget shows nothing on running. If I disable the CloudKit part, the widget works perfectly fine.

[image: widget image]

Answer (score 0):

You were right to disable CloudKit in the widget code, but you didn't say how. The standard way is to still use the `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer` but set the `cloudKitContainerOptions` to nil.

Eg

```
if widget {     
   storeDescription.cloudKitContainerOptions = nil
}
```

You obviously still need your app's code to have valid `cloudKitContainerOptions`.

Comment: I'm sorry for troubling you, but could you explain with a code snippet how I can use the `NSPersitentCloudKitContainer` in my Widget? A detailed explanation would also work. Thanks

Comment: Sure it's pretty simple but I added code above